# find text and copy adjacent cell to different sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I need help. I need to search my worksheet and find a specific word ("substances"), then copy the value in the cell 2 columns over into a different sheet.

For example, in Sheet1, if "substances" was found in A4, then copy value from C4 and paste into Sheet2 under last filled row. I need to continue doing this for the entire worksheet. "Substances" does not occur sequentially, but always in column A (i.e. the first occurrence may be A4, the ext one might be in A16).

Here's what I have so far:

```
Dim Cell, cRange As Range
    Set cRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A75")
    For Each Cell In cRange
    FindCounter = 0

    If Cell.Value = "Substances" Then
        FindCounter = FindCounter + 1
        Sheets("Sheet1").Cell.Value(0, 2).Copy
        Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End If
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: What happens with that code, or doesn't happen? Are there errors?

Comment: I guess this errors `Sheets("Sheet1").Cell.Value(0, 2).Copy`?

Comment: How about just usgin `VLookUp` for this? seems like a perfect match for your scenario

Comment: I do get an error with that line of code: Sheets("Sheet1").Cell.Value(0, 2).Copy

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Find is more efficient than looping (for reasons I have never fully understood).

```
Sub x()

Dim rFind As Range, s As String

With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A75")
    Set rFind = .Find(What:="Substances", Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not rFind Is Nothing Then
        s = rFind.Address
        Do
            Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value = rFind.Offset(, 2).Value
            Set rFind = .FindNext(rFind)
         Loop While rFind.Address <> s
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative using for loop:

```
Sub Copy()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim lRow1 As Long, lRow2 As Long
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

    'set worksheets
    Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")

    'set last row to search for substances
    lRow1 = ws1.Range("A" & ws1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    'start for loop
    For i = 1 To lRow1
        If ws1.Range("A" & i).Value = "Substances" Then
            'assuming you want to paste into column A on sheet 2
            'adjust as you need to
            lRow2 = ws2.Range("A" & ws2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

            ws2.Range("A" & lRow2).Value = ws1.Range("A" & i).Offset(0, 2).Value
        End If
    Next
    'clear objects
    Set ws1 = Nothing
    Set ws2 = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I appreciate both options. Fortunately (or unfortunately) I'm not getting an error message, but for some reason it will not copy/paste.